# Splash Screen won't show in JAR

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am developing a small program for my father and I am using NetBeans as IDE  and the Java Swing toolkit for the GUI.

I set a splash screen to show before the GUI loads and seems to work fine when running the project from NetBeans. But when I start the program from the JAR file, the splash screen won't load.

I've already added the line `"SplashScreen-Image: view/Splash_Screen.gif"` into the manifest.ms file and also added the line `"-splash:src/view/Splash_Screen.gif"` to Project Properties -> Run -> VM Options.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. Right click on the project, went to Properties -> Application -> Splash Screen -> Browse (browse to the location of the splash screen file and add it).